# New SQLAlchemy Add Record Error

Tags: sqlalchemy

Newbie to SQLAlchemy.

I'm having trouble adding a record. I modeled the add after the tutorial which passes multiple values (albeit hard coded values.) Attached is the routine and the error.

StackOverflow thinks my 'explanation to code' ratio is off, so I'm adding additional explanation so I can submit my query.

```
import pdb
from table import wrl
from sqlalchemy import or_, and_, desc, asc
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

rs = create_engine('credentials', echo=True)
aws = create_engine('credentials', echo=True)

rs_session = sessionmaker(bind=rs)
aws_session = sessionmaker(bind=aws)

rs = rs_session()
aws = aws_session()

# pdb.set_trace()

y = rs.query(wrl).order_by(wrl.UUID_PK).first()

cat = y.Added_Timestamp    #now we have the oldest record time stamp value

query_string = cat[:8]+"%"      #now we have the oldest record's date i.e. substring(20111215_121212;1;8)

move_me = rs.query(wrl).filter(wrl.Added_Timestamp.like(query_string)).limit(10)
pdb.set_trace()

for x in move_me:
#     pdb.set_trace()
    wrl_rec = wrl(x.UUID_PK,
                x.Web_Request_Headers,
                x.Web_Request_Body,
                x.Current_Machine,
                x.Current_Machine,
                x.ResponseBody,
                x.Full_Log_Message,
                x.Remote_Address,
                x.basic_auth_username,
                x.Request_Method,
                x.Request_URI,
                x.Request_Protocol,
                x.Time_To_Process_Request,
                x.User_ID,
                x.Error,
                x.Added_Timestamp,
                x.Processing_Time_Milliseconds,
                x.mysql_timestamp)
    aws.add(wrl_rec)
    aws.commit()
    print 'added %s ' %  x.UUID_PK


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "migrate.py", line 47, in <module>
    x.mysql_timestamp)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (19 given)
```

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: what is wrl? from table import wrl this is your module or any python module?

Comment: it's my table definition. Sorry, I'm so new at this I don't know what I don't know. That's where the problem lies. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not really `SA` related. My conjecture is that your constructor (`wrl.__init__(self, ...)`) is either not defined, or does not take any positional arguments, which you are trying to specify when creating this object in `wrl_rec`.

So basically, the error message is pretty much indicating your problem.

*On a side-note, does `order_by(wrl.UUID_PK)` really return the oldest record by the Timestamp as your comment few lines below indicate? Somehow I highly doubt that.*

Comment: I'll check, er, add the non-existent __init__ function and see what that does.And you're right about the order_by. Tweaked that for other testing purposes and didn't untweak. Thanks.